# Is this symbolic statement impossible?

Tags: logic, intuition

Is this statement logically impossible if x is a *single* real number (i.e. not a *set*)?

> > $$(x<5) \land(x>7)$$

it seems to me that x cannot both  be greater than 7 **and** less than 5 if it is a single number on the [numberline](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1833347/which-natural-english-interpretation-of-this-symbolic-statement-is-correct)

Comment: You said it yourself.

Comment: x is an element of an empty set: $x\in \{ \ \}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, the statement

> $x < 5 \wedge x > 7$

is logically false. Equivalently, the statement

> There exists an $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x < 5$ and $x > 7$

is logically false.

Answer (score 3):

Provided that the domain that $x$ varies over is $\mathbb{R}$, and that $<,>,5,7$ all have their normal meanings in this domain, the statement $$(x< 5) \land (x > 7)$$ is not true for any choice of $x$.

I'm not sure you'd want to call this a *logical* impossibility though, as there is nothing about logic that restricts $x\in \mathbb{R}$, or fixes non-logical symbols to have a particular interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right, this is impossible.

Though, if you talk about sets :

$$(x<5)\cap (x>7)=\varnothing.$$

Comment: Sorry, obviously you are right ! I edited.

Comment: I will remove my original comment to prevent any confusion.